# How to get previous letter values if possible in regex?

Tags: python, regex

```
found = re.findall('[ACE][...]'
```

In the second dotted character I need it to be one of these letters: [ADF], but this character mustn't be the first found character (from the [ACE]).
Is there any way I could do that? I know how to do this without regex, but it would be cool to learn to code this in regex.

The regex should do something similar.

```
s = input()
counter = 0
for i in range(len(s) - 1):
    if s[i] in 'ACE':
        if s[i + 1] in 'ADF' and s[i] != s[i + 1]:
            counter += 1
```

I don't necessarily need for the findall method to return me a number, just needed matches will be enough

Comment: You must be asking for `[ACE]([ADF])`

Comment: In this simple case you can use `A[DF]|[CE][ADF]`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a capture group for the first character class `([ACE])`

Then use a negative lookahead `(?!\1)` to assert that the character from the second character class is not the same as what is captured in group 1 using a backreference.

```
([ACE])(?!\1)[ADF]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aTWw6o/1)